# Php and Mongodb not getting connected

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7.1

I have tried the following example in order to display the collection count. Here is what I did:

```
<?php
 $connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(Mongo URI);
//echo phpinfo();
$collection = new MongoDB\Collection($connection, "new", "items");
$initialCollectionCount = $collection->count();
echo $initialCollectionCount;
?>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Collection' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 4
```

What I did till now:
1) Downloaded the latest MongoDB drivers from the Pecl website for PHP 7.1.
2) added the DLL file to `ext` folder and edited the `php.ini` file.
3) Written code for the php and mongo Connection.

Kindly suggest me what I need to do to make my code run. Please note that I have added the System variable as PHP folder. There is nothing that I have not done till now.

Please suggest me the right track so my code get implemented.

Comment: Did you try to add this line: `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: got this erro `Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 2`

Comment: Try using Query class of this latest extension. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try retrieving the data using `MongoDB\Driver\Query` class of the extension.

```
// Manager Class / Connection
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(Mongo URI);

// Query Class like this. Add your conditions here if there may be any
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(array('id' => 1));

// Output of the executeQuery will be object of MongoDB\Driver\Cursor class
$cursor = $connection->executeQuery('new.items', $query);

// Convert cursor to Array and print result
print_r($cursor->toArray());
```

And then you can count the elements of output array.

This code runs fine when you are using latest `MongoDB` extension of `PHP`, `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` is the main entry point to the extension.

**Answer to your comment:** I didn't see a class to list all the collections. Alternatively, try using `Mongo client` until we get more support on `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`

Here is a sample code to list all collections from your database:

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB("new");
$collections = $db->listCollections();

foreach ($collections as $collection) {
    echo "amount of documents in $collection: ";
    echo $collection->count(), "\n";
}

?>
```

The class `MongoClient` is part of the legacy PECL package [mongo](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) but not anymore of the up-to-date mogodb package.

> This package has been superseded, but is still maintained for bugs and
>   security fixes.

Comment: I tried Satish. But is now showing nothing. I am trying to show the list of all the collections in my mongodb. Can you show me?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Well, I don't think and never found a good support on `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` so you can try using `Mongo Client` for more available options until we get an incredible support on Driver Manager.

Comment: @JafferWilson I didn't see any class to list all collections but data from a particular collection. What error you see when you try running my suggested code?

Comment: I could not see the collection list from the database `new`

Comment: @JafferWilson Code using MongoClient is to show all the collections but the code I wrote in the starting is to get the data from a particular collection. I am assuming that your database name is `new` and collection name is `items`. Isn't it?